# Show that a relation is a equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, equivalence-relations

I have a infinite set $A$, and $F$ is the set of all functions $g \colon A \to A$. Let the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $F$ be defined such that $f \sim g$ if only if the set  $D_{fg} = \{ a \in A | f(a) \neq g(a)\}$ is finite. I want to show that $\sim$ really is an equivalence relation.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE,  this site uses  [MathJAx ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) for typing the questions.  Moreover, it is mendatory here to add your own  attempts and the difficulty you faced so that others can help you.

Comment: What have you showed so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have shown the reflexivity and simetry property, but I'm stuck at transitivity property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is direct that the relation is reflexive and symmetric.

Hint on transitivity:

$$D_{fh}\subseteq D_{fg}\cup D_{gh}$$

Comment: Thanks. The reflexivity and simetry are easy. But I still have no idea about transitivity, even with your hint. Can you help me a bit more please?

Comment: Essence of hint: if $D_{fg}$ and $D_{gh}$ are finite sets then also $D_{fh}$ will - as a subset of a finite set - be finite.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a measurable space with some conveniently defined $\mu$ on it, your binary relation can be turned into an equivalence $f\sim g$ in the sense $f$ and $g$ are equal "almost everywhere", that is to say everywhere but on a set $D_{fg}$ of measure zero. $\mu(D_{fg})=0$. This is commonly done in the theory of integration. But you have to ship $A$ with a $\sigma$-additive measure of sets.

The relation $R(f,g)$: the  set $D_{fg}=\{x\in A, f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is negligible (has measure zero) is an equivalence relation (symmetric, reflexive, and transitive) not only because,

$D_{fh}=\{x\in A, f(x)\neq h(x)\}\subset D_{fg}=\{x\in A, f(x)\neq g(x)\} \cup D_{gh}=\{x\in A, g(x)\neq h(x)\}$

but conversely because the union of two negligible sets is a negligible set. The concept of $\sigma$-additive set measurability is at the heart of the proof.

Comment: This only transfers (and also complicates) the problem. In that context it must be proved that "being  equal a.e." is an equivalence relation. Also it might be that the OP has no familiarity with measure-theory at all.

Comment: measure sigma-additivity implies that the measure of the union of two set of measure zero is zero. Measure theory is at the heart of the proof.